# Swift: How to properly configure Chat Cells for Incoming and Outgoing Message for all Kinds

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a chat layout to display cell for incoming and outgoing kind of messages. I have been able to make it work by activating and deactivating Constraints, except for the Text Message Kind. I noticed that on `prepareForReuse()` the constraints for outgoing cell get distorted.

I will like to know how I can fix this or a better alternative to solve the problem.

This is a video of what happens when I scroll.

[image]

**TextMessageCell.swift**

```
class TextMessageCell: ChatBaseCell {

override var viewModel: ChatCommonRepresentable? {
    didSet {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel as? MessageModel else {return}
        let isIncoming = viewModel.isIncomming
        messageLabel.text = viewModel.message
        self.message = viewModel.message
        sentLabel.text = viewModel.sentDateString

        bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = isIncoming ? .white : Color.solid08.value
        messageLabel.textColor = isIncoming ? .black : .white

        if isIncoming {
            leadingConstraint.isActive = true
            trailingConstraint.isActive = false
        } else {
            sentLabel.setTicker(status: viewModel.status)
            leadingConstraint.isActive = false
            trailingConstraint.isActive = true
        }
    }
}

private lazy var messageLabel: UITextViewFixed = {
    let label = UITextViewFixed()
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.isEditable = false
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.isScrollEnabled = false
    label.dataDetectorTypes = [.flightNumber, .calendarEvent, .address, .phoneNumber, .link, .lookupSuggestion]
    label.isSelectable = true
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.delaysContentTouches = true
    label.font = Font(.installed(.OpenSansRegular), size: .standard(.bodySmall)).instance
    label.linkTextAttributes?[NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle] = NSUnderlineStyle.single
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

private lazy var sentLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.textColor = Color.custom(hexString: "#C8CAD3", alpha: 1.0).value
    label.font = Font(.installed(.OpenSansSemiBold), size: .custom(10)).instance
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

private lazy var bubbleBackgroundView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var widthFullConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var sentLabelBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var sentLabelCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var messageLabelBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var messageLabelCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var messageLabelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var message: String! {
    didSet {
        let constantHeight: CGFloat = message.height(withConstrainedWidth: 250 - 32 - 8, font: Font(.installed(.OpenSansRegular), size: .standard(.bodySmall)).instance)
        let constantWidth: CGFloat = message.width(withConstrainedHeight: constantHeight, font: Font(.installed(.OpenSansRegular), size: .standard(.bodySmall)).instance)
        print(constantWidth)
        if constantHeight < 21 {
            if constantWidth > 230 {
                sentLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = false
                sentLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = true

                messageLabelTopConstraint.isActive = true
                messageLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = false
                messageLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = true

                widthConstraint = bubbleBackgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250)
                widthConstraint.isActive = true
            } else {
                sentLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = true
                sentLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = false

                messageLabelTopConstraint.isActive = false
                messageLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = true
                messageLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = false

                guard let user = UserDefaults().currentUser() else {return}
                let isIncoming = "\(user.id!)" != viewModel!.sender.id

                if isIncoming {
                    let fullWidth = constantWidth + 70
                    widthFullConstraint.constant = fullWidth
                    widthFullConstraint.isActive = true
                } else {
                    let fullWidth = constantWidth + 90
                    widthFullConstraint.constant = fullWidth
                    widthFullConstraint.isActive = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private func constraintViews() {

}

override func setupViews() {

    addSubview(bubbleBackgroundView)
    bubbleBackgroundView.addSubview(messageLabel)
    bubbleBackgroundView.addSubview(sentLabel)

    bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor.align(to: topAnchor)
    bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.align(to: bottomAnchor)

    messageLabel.trailingAnchor.align(to: bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor, offset: -8)
    messageLabel.leadingAnchor.align(to: bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor, offset: 8)

    sentLabel.trailingAnchor.align(to: bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor, offset: -10)
    sentLabel.widthAnchor.equal(to: 70)

    leadingConstraint = bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20)
    leadingConstraint.isActive = false

    trailingConstraint = bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20)
    trailingConstraint.isActive = true

    widthConstraint = bubbleBackgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250)
    widthConstraint.isActive = true

    widthFullConstraint = bubbleBackgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)
    widthFullConstraint.isActive = false

    messageLabelTopConstraint = messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor, constant: 10)
    messageLabelTopConstraint.isActive = false

    messageLabelBottomConstraint = bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -18)
    messageLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = true

    messageLabelCenterYConstraint = messageLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleBackgroundView.centerYAnchor)
    messageLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = false

    sentLabelBottomConstraint = sentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
    sentLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = true

    sentLabelCenterYConstraint = sentLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleBackgroundView.centerYAnchor)
    sentLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = false
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    sentLabel.text = nil
    messageLabel.text = nil

    leadingConstraint.isActive = false
    trailingConstraint.isActive = false
    widthConstraint.isActive = false
    sentLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = false
    sentLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = false
    messageLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = false
    messageLabelCenterYConstraint.isActive = false
    messageLabelTopConstraint.isActive = false
    widthFullConstraint.isActive = false
    }
}
```

Comment: `prepareForReuse` you should only use to reset attributes that are related to the appearance of the cell (for example, alpha, editing, and selection state) and not constraints. Solution to your problem is, you can have two cells, one is for incoming messages and it will be sticked with left, another one is for outgoing cell that will be sticked to the right side. cell chosen has to happen in 
`cellForRowAtIndexPath`. by doing this way you can get performance improvements as well.

Comment: You can create two prototype cells. One for incoming and another for outgoing message. Then using same condition to identify the message type, you can just return the required cell.

Comment: I understand, I thought of that as well, but I want to be sure if its a good solution as I would have to create an outgoing and incoming cell for all type of messages like text, image, video, contact, location e.t.c. Won't that result in redundancy? @karthik

Comment: @SimpiMind. it gives good performance without any glitches. if you use asyncKit with this brings out the 60FPS. till now am good with the above implementation rather toggling constraints.